# Game Engine: How to transpose Variables from structs: Coding practices

Tags: c++, struct

I am programming a gameengine.

So, every `node` has some properties. 
For this I set up an `array` of a `struct` like this:

```
struct propertyTemplate {
propertyTemplate (QString namei, QString valuei, QString expectedi, bool changedi = false) {
    name = namei;
    value = valuei;
    expected = expectedi;
    changed = changedi;
}

QString name;
QString value;
QString expected; //What the programm expects;
bool changed = false; //if these are the default values
};
```

-

```
std::vector<propertyTemplate> properties;
```

This gets filled up in runtime like this:

```
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Name", "creativeName", "string"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Sprite-link", "", "link"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Height", "100", "float"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Width", "100", "float"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Position X", "0", "float"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Position Y", "0", "float"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Rotation", "0", "string"));
```

This all gets filled into a `treeWidget` and **now the catch**:

When the user changes the property, how can I put it also into the variable of the class which contains the array of properties?

```
class CSprite2D {
private: 
    std::vector<propertyTemplate> properties;
    QString name; //I want the value of "name" in propertyTemplate
                  //to go into here BUT by JUST changing the                                     
                  //value in properties, as I don't know (from an external class) which variable contains which value.
}
```

-

I don't want a solution that simply works (that would be a while-loop which checks if the property was changed), but also one that is elegant and doesn't imply having sneeky workarounds.

*these examples were fictional, so don't mind possible programming errors*

BTW: As I am new to C++ there might be something crucial which I forgot about.
In this case, I'm really sorry

Comment: Check out the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: To the downvoter: It's unclear what he's asking because he's not really sure what is needed, I think...

Comment: Thank you @Steve

Comment: @Steve How could I implement an observer pattern? Is it a while-loop or does Qt come with an observer class??? Another way I could solve my problem is by using pointer to functions if those do exist. Do they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, about coding style:
What compiler you are using?  Normally you don't need such constructor,  with C++11 (or C99) you can use syntax:

struct propertyTemplate s {QString(name),QString(value), QString(expectedi)};

And it is proper to use initialization list

```
propertyTemplate (QString namei, QString valuei, QString expectedi, bool changedi = false):
    name(namei),
    value(valuei),
    expected(expectedi),
    changed(changedi)
{}
```

Yu may try to use observer-like pattern, that would make use of [[pointer to member of class]] it must update when changing particular value